# json decode issue with bing data (python)

Tags: python, json, bing, bing-api

I am in trouble with the bing's json api.

Here is the json data i am receiving from api.bing.net/json.aspx:

> {"SearchResponse":{"Version":"2.2","Query":{"SearchTerms":"news"},"Translation":{"Results":[{"TranslatedTerm":"Noticias"}]}}}

I need to parse the TranslatedTerm value "Noticias" but it seems i have a problem with the json decode. I am using this..

```
           result = j.loads(bytes)
            print result['SearchResponse']['Translation']['Results']
```

And python gives me this:

> [{u'TranslatedTerm': u'Noticias'}]

If i add use it like this:

> result['SearchResponse']['Translation']['Results']["TranslatedTerm"]

python raises an error like

```
print result['SearchResponse']['Translation']['Results']["TranslatedTerm"]
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers

How can i get the 'Noticias' as a plain string? Much appriciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation `Results` is a list - presumably because there can be many results.

If you're sure you're only interested in the first result, you can do this:

```
result['SearchResponse']['Translation']['Results'][0]['TranslatedTerm']
```